# Simple C language code issue

Tags: c

I'm currently practicing C language, and having a problem with a simple basic coding that will average number of scores on school subjects.

Here are the codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a;
int sub, score;
float totalscore = 0;

printf("How many subjects to average? - 8 or less subjects - \n");
    scanf("%d", &sub);

    if(sub > 8)
    { 
        printf("number of subjects cannot be more than 8 \n");
    }

printf("Enter score for each subjects \n");
    for(a =1;a <= sub;a++)
    {
        printf("Subject %d : ", a);
        scanf("%d", &score);
        totalscore = totalscore + score;
    }

printf("Total %d number of subjects' average is %.2f", sub, totalscore/sub);

return 0;
}
```

If someone enters the number of subjects they wish to average, it continues by saying "enter score for each subjects" and they will be able to enter in the scores for each subject.

so my problem is if more than 8 number of subjects were put in, how do you make the program to not continue? and just stay there but, display "number of subjects cannot be more than 8"?

I assuming this is a pretty simple problem, but I didn't know how to word this problem out to search on Google.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, C is C and C++ is C++. Don't feel the need to tag a question about one with both.

Comment: Well, you could write `for (;;) {}` inside `if(sub > 8){...}`. Somehow I don't think that's quite what you had in mind, but that would quite literally make the program to "not continue".

Comment: You can use `return 1` in the `if` statement that checks for more than 8 subjects. When you return from main, it stops executing the program.

Comment: `for(a =1;a <= sub;a++)` - ***No, please, pretty please, just no!*** `for (a = 0; a < sub; a++)` is enough. And **use whitespace, and use it consistently.** Formatting matters.

Answer (score 3):

In case you wanted to allow the user to try again, you could put the code that gets the number of subjects into a loop that keeps going until the user inputs a valid number.

```
sub = 9;
while (sub > 8 || sub < 1)
{
    printf("How many subjects to average? - 8 or less subjects - \n");
    scanf("%d", &sub);

    if (sub > 8)
    {
        printf("number of subjects cannot be more than 8\n");
    }
    else if (sub < 1)
    {
        printf("number of subjects cannot be less than 1\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1432136 you might want to check out my solution as well, same concept as this answer but coded in a different way

Answer (score 1):

Think about your logic. You have it mostly correct. You're checking for the error condition, but what are you doing if that error condition is true? Another answer has suggested using the exit() function, and that will certainly work in this scenario, but your problem exposes a gap in your understanding of programming logic - one which if you figure it out now, it will save you headache in the future.

Behold, the **else** statement!

```
// Check for "too many" subjects
if(sub > 8)
{
    printf("number of subjects cannot be more than 8 \n");
}
// Only allow processing if the number of subjects was <= 8
else
{
    // for loop processing for input goes here
}
```

The if/else series of statements ensures **one and only one** of the branches executes. This can be further complicated by *else if* statements to allow for more than one condition, as follows:

```
// Check for "too many" subjects
if(sub > 8)
{
    printf("number of subjects cannot be more than 8 \n");
}
// Check for "too few" subjects
else if(sub < 1)
{
    printf("number of subjects cannot be less than 1 \n");
}
// Only allow processing if the number of subjects was <= 8
else
{
    // for loop processing for input goes here
}
```

Please note the importance of the "else if" as opposed to "if". In situations where all conditional logic is an "if" statement, it's possible for more than one to execute, because they're not mutually exclusive. If/else if/else are all mutually exclusive, whereas if/if/if can execute all branches (assuming the conditions they check are not inherently mutually exclusive, like the case above -- a number cannot be greater than 8 and less than 1 at the same time).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! made me to think about more logically, and now it seems it wasn't a hard thing for me after all.

Comment: Great! Glad I was able to help. Be sure to upvote any answers which helped you, and to mark the one which was most helpful as "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
if(sub > 8)
{ 
    fprintf(stderr, "number of subjects cannot be more than 8 \n");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);

}
```

Comment: `exit(-1)` is not portable; it should probably be `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`. And error messages should usually be written to `stderr`.

Comment: Of course, I was just going by OP's program which was printing to stdout. Updated answer anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If all you'd like to do is make the program stop, then

```
if (sub > 8)
{ 
    printf("number of subjects cannot be more than 8 \n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

should be sufficient, though if you want to do something afterwards, you could write an `else` condition as well and wrap the rest of your code in the `else` block:

```
if (sub > 8)
{ 
    printf("number of subjects cannot be more than 8 \n");
}
else
{
    // Rest of code here
}
```

You may also consider replacing `return 0` with `return EXIT_SUCCESS` to make your code a bit more descriptive.

Answer (score -1):

you can try the following:

```
while(sub > 8)
{ 
    printf("number of subjects cannot be more than 8 \n");
    printf("How many subjects to average? - 8 or less subjects - \n");
   scanf("%d", &sub);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In your loop just use `if(a == 8) break;`

```
for(a =1;a <= sub;a++) {
        if(a == 8) break; // it interrupts this loop
        printf("Subject %d : ", a);
        scanf("%d", &score);
        totalscore = totalscore + score;
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to exit your program completely use `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` in your first check.